# この質問の改善点はどこですか？ 「Linuxカーネルをアップデートすると動かない、あるいは挙動がおかしくなるアプリを教えてください」

Tags: 討議, クローズ理由

改善待ちになっている質問「[Linuxカーネルをアップデートすると動かない、あるいは挙動がおかしくなるアプリを教えてください。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/34173/3054)」ですが、既に指摘されている点はだいぶ改善されたかと思います。
十分でないとしたら、質問者さんには他にどうしてよいか解らない状態だと思いますので、さらなる改善点の指摘、あるいは編集による改善をよろしくお願いします。

---

回答ありがとうございます。
どうも、ディストリビューション（のバージョン）間での非互換性などの話題と混同されている可能性があるようですね。
念のために確認しておきますが、このような非互換性は基本的にユーザー空間の問題です。
件の質問は「glibcに依存するなどユーザ空間の問題ではなく」と述べられている通り、こういった非互換性にまつわるリストを求めるような物ではありません。

「サポート打ち切りリ‌​スト」などとは異なり、明確に技術的観点から回答可能で、該当する物も「データベース」となるほどの数は無いはずです。
少なくとも、私の知る限りでは、常識的にこのように考えられていて、多くのシステムがそれを前提としています。

Answer (score -2):

私の理解は浅いけど浅いなりの回答
CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso
これは最小構成のCentOSのイメージだが680MBある。
CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1611.iso 
これにいたっては7.71GBある
仮に最小構成がカーネルが500Mだとしたら
Everythingはカーネルの14倍7G分プログラムがある。

Minimal内にどれだけコマンドがあるか
（とりあえずパッと思いついたのがこれだったのでこれ）

```
ls /bin | cat -n
```

を実行すると
最終行が654行になる。それだけコマンドがあるということになる。
1Mにつき１コマンド
Everythingで7710か非公式や自分でコンパイルするもの含めネットからもっと落とせるので、軽く見積もって２倍にしたとして15000コマンドになる。

> 特定のハードウェアを制御する目的で、専用のモジュールを前提としているプログラムは含みません。

焼け石に水だけど一万まで減らす。
さらにコマンドの集合をアプリとして考えるために100分の一まで減らす。
10個でもリストっぽいけど100個になるデータベースのレベル

データベースはやめてくれってどこかに書いてあったはず。

別の視点からは

> カーネルバージョンを上げると動かなくなる or 挙動がおかしくなる例を知りたいのです

知って何がしたいの？再現がしたいの？
それって興味本位ではない？

ここでできる質問は：
Dockerで某アプリを使ったら動かなかったとか挙動がおかしい原因教えて

が限度で

> 『アプリがLinuxのカーネルバージョンに依存するのでカーネルをアップデートできない』と聞きますが、

掲示板やブログの過去の発言なら聞けなかったかもですが、発言者に直接聞くしかなかったですね。

＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿￥
追記について

手元にある（数日前からテザリングでダウンロードしてる。）
CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1611.iso をvmで動かしてどうすればいいんだ。いい経験になると思うから、教えてくれやる。

けど、ディストリビューションを構成するために意図的にコミュニティーは
カーネルのバージョン下げてるとかそういうことしてる。から、微妙だとは思うんだけど。

```
ディストリビューションのバージョン

　主なディストリビューション　　      リリース日　カーネルバージョン　
  RedHat Enterprise Linux 7         2014/6    3.10
  Fedora 21                         2014/12   3.17
  SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12   2014/10   3.12
  Ubuntu 14.10                      2014/10   3.16
  CentOS 7.3                        2016/12   3.10

参考
有限会社ナレッジデザイン大竹龍史 著,翔泳社,Linux教科書 LPICレベル2 スピードマスター問題集 Version4.0対応,ISBN:9784798141015
最後のはwiki
```

今の最新版は4.11メジャー番号が変わった理由が３の時とほぼ同じ

Comment: ご指摘の通り、CentOS、あるいは Linux 一般で動作するアプリケーションは沢山ありますね。
その中に存在するかも知れない「Linuxカーネルをアップデートすると動かない、あるいは挙動がおかしくなるアプリ」が件の質問で問われている内容になります。
仮に、インストール直後の CentOS に大量に存在する、という事になると、例えば [CentOS ベースのdocker イメージ](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/)の運用方法などは見直さなければいけませんし、 それ以前にあらゆる場所で問題が噴出するでしょうから、「知って何がしたいの？」というのはある程度自明ですし、むしろ「やらねばならない事」が大量にあるはずです。

Comment: ディストリビューションが異なればLinxカーネルからdocker間のミドルウエアが異なる可能性があります。その違いのみを提供するのがDockerですよね。要するに環境に依存した言語の開発者にとって環境再現作業の軽減や負荷軽減が目的なわけですよね。それでも[Linuxのディストリビューション](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%83%93%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3)は多い.この質問を端的に聞きなおすなら暴論ですがカーネルがアップデートで使えなくなったアプリWindowsならXPから１０にアップデートして使えなくなったアプリです。要するにサポート打ち切りリストです。

Comment: どうも誤解があると思いますので、Meta質問に補足しました。